# WooCommerce Orders metabox: Run php code on custom submit action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, meta-boxes

In Woocommerce, I have been able to add a custom submit button on order edit page in a custom metabox.

Here is my code *(added in `function.php` Wordpress theme)*:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'MY_order_meta_boxes' );
function MY_order_meta_boxes() {

    add_meta_box(
        'woocommerce-order-verifyemail',
        __( 'Trusted List' ),
        'order_meta_box_content',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'default'
    );
}

function order_meta_box_content( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce, $table_prefix, $wpdb;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $customeremail = $order->get_billing_email();
    ?>

        <form method="post" action="CURRENT_FILE_URL">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($submit)) {$order->add_order_note(sprintf("test2"));}
    ?>

    <?php
    return $order_id;
}
```

But I don't know why, the code doesn't run when button is clicked (submitted).

How can I run some custom code, when submit button is clicked on this custom metabox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work as you expect you need some more things. I have also removed unnecessary code and some errors. Also `<imput>` `"submit"` ID is too generic and can make unexpected errors.

You will be able to do any action (or saves) in a custom function hooked in **`save_post`** action hook:

```
// Add a custom metabox
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'trusted_list_order_meta_boxes' );
function trusted_list_order_meta_boxes() {

    add_meta_box(
        'woocommerce-order-verifyemail',
        __( 'Trusted List' ),
        'trusted_list_order_meta_box_content',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'default'
    );
}

// Custom metabox content
function trusted_list_order_meta_box_content( $post ){
    $customeremail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_billing_email', true);
    $button_text = __( 'Add Note action', 'woocommerce' );

    echo '<form method="post" action="CURRENT_FILE_URL">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_trusted_list" value="' . $button_text . '"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="trusted_list_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">
    </form>';
}

// Saving or doing an action when submitting
add_action( 'save_post', 'trusted_list_save_meta_box_data' );
function trusted_list_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ){

    // Only for shop order
    if ( 'shop_order' != $_POST[ 'post_type' ] )
        return $post_id;

    // Check if our nonce is set (and our cutom field)
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'trusted_list_nonce' ] ) && isset( $_POST['submit_trusted_list'] ) )
        return $post_id;

    $nonce = $_POST[ 'trusted_list_nonce' ];

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce ) )
        return $post_id;

    // Checking that is not an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Check the user’s permissions (for 'shop_manager' and 'administrator' user roles)
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $post_id ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    // Action to make or (saving data)
    if( isset( $_POST['submit_trusted_list'] ) ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
        // $customeremail = $order->get_billing_email();
        $order->add_order_note(sprintf("test2"));
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works. You will get:

[image]

> In your custom Metabox **content** function **you will not be able to get any data** using **`$_POST`** submitted data… So for example **`$_POST['submit']`** will be **always empty**.

Comment: @LoicTheAztech  can you made that button  javascript?

Comment: @Mostafa what do you mean: "made that button javascript?". If you mean "ajax", this is much more complicated and I have no time for that. Is may be better to ask a new question for that…

Answer (score 1):

...I think you should use $_POST['submit'] other than $submit

Comment: you right.  i changed to  $_POST['submit'] but no luck :(