# Export individual order from WP WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to send individual order details from WooCommerce to a 3d party source.
The easiest way I think would be to have an 'Export' button within each order, that would trigger this event.

[image]

The button location would be also fine to be on the right sidebar if it's easier.
I'm new to WP dev so I don't really know where to start or what hooks are better in this case.

After my initial research I've found most of the plugins that are specific to mass order export, which I don't want.

Any hint/guide/example would be welcome.

Comment: Analytics -> Orders from there you can export all orders or filter to get specific order.

Comment: I'll take that as an alternative, since a more convenient way is to do this within the order page where I can see all the details. Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy way to do it without any coding is install to woocommerce Invoice  plugin, there you can generate invoice for each order then you can easily download the order details in PDF :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/

This is an alternative, if you want to do it coding, you need to give more details about the output format , it's PDF or only csv with order details ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yassine. I don't need a specific format for the output, because the data will be sent to a 3rd party (to an external api), using a request (within a php function). Therefore, I need the order data to attach them to that request. First step would be to add the button inside the WC admin area, then I need to handle the action within a hook I assume, where my request will take place. Including invoices will get the things too complicated I think.

Answer (score 1):

The action you are looking for is [`add_meta_boxes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)

Here you can see some working examples: [WooCommerce Orders metabox: Run php code on custom submit action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392169/woocommerce-orders-metabox-run-php-code-on-custom-submit-action)